# MVC 2 Areas not showing up in VS2008 context menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have converted my ASP.NET web forms project into an MVC project by adding the MVC ProjectType guid in the project file. All of my MVC 2 project items are showing up (View, Controller etc.) but for Areas. I have MVC 2 installed so I'm not sure what's not setup right.

Comment: Is that officially supported, I mean converting WebForms project to MVC one?

Comment: @mare, yes you can have a hybrid ASP.NET-MVC project where you could have both classic Web Forms and Views/Controllers reside side-by-side.  MVC is just a routing engine and as long as you have Controllers and Views folders setup in your project, it should work fine. 

Here is a great article on setting this up in your solution: http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc

And here is a flowchart that explains the MVC routing engine in an easy-to-understand manner: http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/be_ahead_of_the_game_poster1.htm

Comment: Looks like 'converted' was not the right word to use here. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that an MVC 2 project has a different GUID which makes sense since they are supposed to work side-by-side. I ended up using {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325} .

P.S: You have to add this at the start of the element like this:

< ProjectTypeGuids >{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}< /ProjectTypeGuids >

It wouldn't load when I added it at the end (as described in Sanderson's book).